# DataTable, How to conditionally delete rows

Tags: c#, datatable, delete-row

I'm engaged in a C# learning process and it is going well so far. I however just now hit my first "say what?" moment.

The DataTable offers random row access to its Rows collection, not only through typical collections behavior, but also through DataTable.Select. However I cannot seem to be able to tie this ability to DataRow.Delete. So far this is what it seems I need to do in order to conditionally delete one or more rows from a table.

```
int max = someDataTable.Rows.Count - 1;
for(int i = max; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if((int)someDataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0] == someValue)
    {
        someDataTable.Rows[i].BeginEdit();
        someDataTable.Rows[i].Delete();
    }
    else
        break;
}
someDataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

But I'm not happy with this code. Neither I'm convinced. I must be missing something. Am I really forced to hit the Rows collection sequentially if I need to delete one or more rows conditionally?

(don't mind the inverted for. I'm deleting from the end of the datatable. So it's ok)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could query the dataset and then loop the selected rows to set them as delete.

```
var rows = dt.Select("col1 > 5");
foreach (var row in rows)
   { row.Delete(); }
   dt.AcceptChanges();
```

... and you could also create some extension methods to make it easier ...

```
myTable.Delete("col1 > 5");

public static DataTable Delete(this DataTable table, string filter)
{
    table.Select(filter).Delete();
    return table;
}
public static void Delete(this IEnumerable<DataRow> rows)
{
    foreach (var row in rows)
        row.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Ah! Didn't occur to me Select() would return a reference to the datatable rows. I knew I had to be missing something. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Too good solution, this also solved my problem of datatable.select changing the order.

Comment: Finally You want to apply those change to dt table using below command.`dt.AcceptChanges()`

Comment: This is a useful approach, BUT, be careful if you need to check one column (rows values) with a variable instead of a simple number, the interpreter will try to find another column with the variable name. Eg: ' var rows = Dt.Select("Col1 < yourVariable); ' , code will try to find rows where [Column.Col1] is less than [Column.yourVariable] which will give you an error.

Answer (score 48):

Here's a one-liner using LINQ and avoiding any run-time evaluation of select strings:

```
someDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(
    r => r.ItemArray[0] == someValue).ToList().ForEach(r => r.Delete());
```

Comment: Sometime, remember call function someDataTable.AcceptChanges(); after delete

Comment: @GreyWolf if you want to write the changes back to the database, then do NOT call AcceptChanges! AcceptChanges will mark all new/updated rows as unchanged, thus the DataAdapter will think there are NO changes and won't write anything to the database on .Update().

Comment: what is r.ItemArray[0] in this case, is it the first column of the row? please tag me when you reply.

Comment: Very nice and elegant code this is. I was searching for this trick since two days! And thank you so much @Alain to post this code 'coz you saved my day.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have a windows box handy to try this but I think you can use a DataView and do something like so:

```
DataView view = new DataView(ds.Tables["MyTable"]);
view.RowFilter = "MyValue = 42"; // MyValue here is a column name

// Delete these rows.
foreach (DataRowView row in view)
{
  row.Delete();
}
```

I haven't tested this, though.  You might give it a try.

Comment: I tried and it worked. I do prefer the Select approach though. But good thing to keep in mind. Thanks :) +1

Comment: This btw would leave the underlying DataTable object intact and "growing" with unused rows, hence, might be memory garbage. It is indeed useful if you want to retrive a different "view" of the DataTable, at a different moment or to a different object. Interesting approach! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Extension method based on Linq

```
public static void DeleteRows(this DataTable dt, Func<DataRow, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(predicate).ToList())
        row.Delete();
}
```

Then use:

```
DataTable dt = GetSomeData();
dt.DeleteRows(r => r.Field<double>("Amount") > 123.12 && r.Field<string>("ABC") == "XYZ");
```