# Deleting row from datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm having a problem deleting rows from a datatable. In my program, I am reading info from a database into a datatable using an sql query. I use an oledb connection and the code `dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());` to do this. Later, I want to delete rows that match an id string. I have tried the following code buy cannot get it to work:

```
            DataRow[] drr = dt.Select("Student=' " + id + " ' "); 
            for (int i = 0; i < drr.Length; i++)
                dt.Rows.Remove(drr[i]);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Can anyone please suggest another way with an example?

Comment: nope no errors. i tried doing printing the row count in the table. its the same before and after the delete method above

Comment: Take a look at following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648339/deleting-specific-rows-from-datatable/31702529

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using [Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03c7a3zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method:

```
    DataRow[] drr = dt.Select("Student=' " + id + " ' "); 
    for (int i = 0; i < drr.Length; i++)
        drr[i].Delete();
    dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: does not work. the row count is again the same before and after. I have a datagrid view displaying the table. it remains unchanged

Comment: Is your `dt.Select("Student...` returning results (non empty array)?

Comment: hmm... it is. I dont know why though. the column name is clearly student as seen in the dgv

Comment: wow i got it! apparently the phrase "Student=' " + id + " ' " had two extra spaces before and after the single quote!

Answer (score 3):

This question will give you good insights on how to delete a record from a DataTable:

[DataTable, How to conditionally delete rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591771/datatable-how-to-conditionally-delete-rows)

It would look like this:

```
DataRow[] drr = dt.Select("Student=' " + id + " ' "); 
foreach (var row in drr)
   row.Delete();
```

Don't forget that if you want to update your database, you are going to need to call the Update command.  For more information on that, see this link:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=471027

Answer (score 3):

There several different ways to do it. But You can use the following approach:

```
List<DataRow> RowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();

for (int i = 0; i < drr.Length; i++) 
{     
   if(condition to delete the row) 
   {  
       RowsToDelete.Add(drr[i]);     
   } 
}

foreach(var dr in RowsToDelete) 
{     
   drr.Rows.Remove(dr); 
}
```

Comment: Hi brother,How did you init RowsToDelete? Is it here? DataRow[] RowsToDelete=null;

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason the OPs code does not work is because once you call Remove you are changing the Length of drr. When you call Delete you are not actually deleting the row until AcceptChanges is called. This is why if you want to use Remove you need a separate loop.

Depending on the situation or preference...

```
string colName = "colName";
string comparisonValue = (whatever it is).ToString();
string strFilter = (dtbl.Columns[colName].DataType == typeof(string)) ? "[" + colName + "]='" + comparisonValue + "'" : "[" + colName + "]=" + comparisonValue;
string strSort = "";

DataRow[] drows = dtbl.Select(strFilter, strSort, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Above used for next two examples

```
foreach(DataRow drow in drows)
{
   drow.Delete();//Mark a row for deletion.
}
dtbl.AcceptChanges();
```

OR

```
foreach(DataRow drow in drows)
{
   dtbl.Rows[dtbl.Rows.IndexOf(drow)].Delete();//Mark a row for deletion.
}
dtbl.AcceptChanges();
```

OR

```
List<DataRow> listRowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();

foreach(DataRow drow in dtbl.Rows)
{
   if(condition to delete)
   {
      listRowsToDelete.Add(drow);
   }
}

foreach(DataRow drowToDelete in listRowsToDelete)
{
   dtbl.Rows.Remove(drowToDelete);// Calling Remove is the same as calling Delete and then calling AcceptChanges
}
```

Note that if you call Delete() then you should call AcceptChanges() but if you call Remove() then AcceptChanges() is not necessary.

[Also, here is a good link on row filter syntax.](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of answers using the Remove method and others using the Delete method.

Remove (according to the docs) will immediately remove the record from the (local) table, and on Update, will not remove a missing record.

Delete in comparison changes the RowState to Deleted, and will update the server table on Update.  Likewise, calling the AcceptChanges method before the Update to the server table will reset all your RowState(s) to Unchanged and nothing will flow to the server.  (Still nursing my thumb after hitting this a number of times).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the **entire row** from **DataTable** ,

try this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  //User DataTable
DataRow[] rows;
rows = dt.Select("Student=' " + id + " ' ");
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
     dt.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Advance `for loop` works better for this case

```
public void deleteRow(DataRow selectedRow)
        {
            foreach (DataRow  in StudentTable.Rows)
            {
                if (SR[TableColumn.StudentID.ToString()].ToString() == StudentIndex)
                    SR.Delete();
            }

            StudentTable.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

a simple example : http://www.dotnetspark.com/tutorial/13-42-delete-row-from-datatable.aspx

Does this work for you?

Comment: i dont know the index position of the row i want to delete. I need to search by the string id in that row

Comment: you can search datatable , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5c0xc84(VS.80).aspx and delete row you need after that.