# Updating a datatable in c#

Tags: c#

I have a datatable storing info about a student classroom. My table looks like this:

```
Student ID     Grade     Absence Count
00001           85             0
00002           95             7
00002           70             5
00003           35             1
```

Dont ask me why there are two id's that are the same... its just the way it is. Now i want to update the absence count for the 00002 id that has absence count of 7. At the same time, i want to delete the 00002 entry that doesnt have the absence count of 7 (in this case the one with count 5). Now i know how to query the table with a select statement and update the 00002 id student with count 7. How can i, at the same time, delete the other entry for the 00002 student? This is my code:

```
foreach(oldCount in absenceCount)
{
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Student ID='" + ID + "' AND Absence Count='" + oldCount);
    dr[0]["Absence Count"] = newCount;
}
```

So here how can i tell the program that if there is another student id whose absence count isnt in the absenceCount list, delete it from the table?

Thanks

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591771/datatable-how-to-conditionally-delete-rows

Comment: You'll need to better define the rules surrounding why you want to delete the 2nd one and update the 1st. Is it positional? Because 7 > 5? because 95 > 70? user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the same select but with the opposite condition on the oldcount, like so

```
foreach(oldCount in absenceCount)
{
  DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Student ID='" + ID + "' AND Absence Count != '" + oldCount);
  dr[0].Delete();
}
```

This will get you that student id but where the absence count is not equal to the old count.

You obviously still have a problem where you have, as Blindy suggested, 2 rows with the same student id and the same absence count.

Comment: oops just tried that, apparently ! is not an accepted query syntax

Comment: Is the repeated row the same student (with the same id) appearing twice, or is it two different students with the same Id each appearing once.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
dr[1].Delete();
```

Comment: No i cannot as the select only gets the rows that have the absence count i want to delete. In other words, the 00002 id row with count 5 will not be in the dr datarow

Comment: @Greg: You can run another `Select()` with a different condition.

Comment: like what? how can i run a select to select a row that doesnt meet the contents of the oldCOunt list?

Comment: One would wonder.. what if there's 2 students with the same id (sigh) and the same number of absences...

Comment: lol this is a test for something bigger, so dont worry about exception cases

Comment: @Greg: `Absence Count <> something`

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand that syntax?

Comment: @Greg: See the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: This might be a dumber question, but why not just mandate a absense count of 7?  How do you "know" you want to delete the one where its != 7? and if you did know, why wouldn't you isolate accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can select all the rows with same ID. Update the one you want to, and delete the rest of the rows. Something like

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Student ID='" + ID + "'");
```

and then updating the one that matches the Absence count, deleting the rest of them.

Regarding the comment:
This is taken from Kenny's reply, but this is what i meant

```
foreach(DataRow row in dr)
{
  if (dr["Absence Count"] == absencCount)
      dr["Absence Count"] = newCount;
  else
      dr.Delete()
}
```

Comment: But how do you get "the rest of them"?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(oldCount in absenceCount)
{
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Student ID='" + ID);
    bool updated = false;
    foreach(DataRow row in dr)
    {
      if (!updated && dr["Absence Count"] == absenceCount)
      {
          dr["Absence Count"] = newCount;
          updated = true;
      }
      else
      {
          dr.Delete()
      }
    }
}
```