# Delete a row by condition from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I created DataTable in my project.Fill it with table in database.

```
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable(Table_Name)

Dim myLocalConnection As New SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)
myLocalConnection.Open()

Dim mySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
myCommand.Connection = myLocalConnection
mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
```

Now i want to delete a specific row from tableby condition.
And update the table on database. with `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` method.

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)
```

How could i do this? help...

Comment: There is a similar question asked on the forum [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648339/deleting-specific-rows-from-datatable

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataTable, How to conditionally delete rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591771/datatable-how-to-conditionally-delete-rows)

Comment: Why now only C# even if you show VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
    if (row ...) // implement your condition here
        myDataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
```

C# code here because you ask for C# in your title.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the `DeleteCommand` of the `DataAdapter`. Then you can use `DataRow.Delete` to change it's row-state to `RowState.Deleted` which causes the dataadapter to delete it from database when you use `DataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)`.

To find the rows that you want to delete you can use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
Dim deleteCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM ...", myLocalConnection)
mySqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = deleteCommand 

Dim query = From row In myDataTable
            Where row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName") = "Delete-Condition"
For Each row As DataRow in query 
    row.Delete()
Next

mySqlDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)
```