# How to remove the last/footer-row in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable which I use it as a datasource for my datagridview:

```
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

but after binding the datatable I get the below result. The last row allows people to click on the row and enter data which I don't want to happen.

How can I remove the last row in run time (highlighted in the picture)[image]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataTable, How to conditionally delete rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591771/datatable-how-to-conditionally-delete-rows)

Comment: This is not about how to delete datatable row, it is about removing the footer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not data table row but so called `NewRow` of `DataGridView` to remove it set property `AllowUserToAddRows` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to `false` for your gird.

You may either set it from code or using visual studio designer.

Comment: correct! Ex:-
dataGridView11.AllowUserToAddRows = false;