# How can I avoid adding new values to a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have one `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and it has 5 values. When I choose one this added a new column like that:

[image]

How to avoid that? I want to have one column with values.
When I disable propery "AllowUserToAddRows" then I dont have any rows. I just wanted to have one row with values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the last/footer-row in DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349216/how-to-remove-the-last-footer-row-in-datagridview)

Comment: yes , sorry i mean new row

Comment: If you never wants to add new row to your grid, follow the answer by gas.

Comment: @DanielD If the solution of DanielD doesn't satisfy your requirement it seems you should describe what you need exactly. Please reword your question and say what you need exactly and use `Column` and `Row` words correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Set  the property "AllowUserToAddRows"  to false for your gird.

Comment: ye, but when I do that I have no more any rows. Only just name of the column.