# Delete multiple records with LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have following piece of code which removes the rows from the `DataTable` based upon `custom_id` as "Y" (i.e. remove the row if value for the key `custom_id` is "Y" in the `dictionary`). Now that I have very few records in list `fldListWithUnlimitedDataEnabled` and relatively huge records in DataTable `objDt`, is there a way to delete the specific rows (as done in `objRow.Delete()`) from `objDt`, so that I don't have to traverse entire `DataTable` for few records?

```
Dim objRow As DataRow
Dim customFlds As Dictionary(Of String, String) = m_objCmnFncs.getCustomFlsdWithUnlimitedDataIndicator(strOrgId)
Dim fldListWithUnlimitedDataEnabled As List(Of String) = (From kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In customFlds
                                                          Where kv.Value.Equals("Y")
                                                          Select kv.Key).ToList
If fldListWithUnlimitedDataEnabled.Count > 0 Then

    For Each objRow In objDt.Rows
        //The below condition effects the performance
        If fldListWithUnlimitedDataEnabled.Contains(objRow("custom_id")) Then
            objRow.Delete()
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but in your example you want Contains, not Equals.

Comment: Thanks...edited the question

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591771/datatable-how-to-conditionally-delete-rows) should give you an idea. It's c#, but the concept is the same for vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

If objDt is a part of a strongly-typed DataSet and custom_id is the primary key of the DataTable, it will have a FindBycustom_id method that will find the row.

The name of the function is auto-generated to be FindBy followed by the primary key name(s).
Then you can iterate through your list of keys, find the row, and delete them.

```
For Each id in fldListWithUnlimitedDataEnabled
    Dim objRow = objDt.FindBycustom_id(id)
    if objRow IsNot Nothing Then objRow.Delete()
Next
```

If that's not an available option, you can always use Select

```
For Each id in fldListWithUnlimitedDataEnabled
    Dim objRows = objDt.Select("custom_id = '" & id & "'")  
    For Each row in objRows 
        row.Delete()
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a part of strongly typed DataSet where custom_id could be a primary key.

Comment: The approach with Select is somewhat useful